# email verification from database using express js node js and angular 6 with mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, angular6

i am creating a user, with 'email' field so i want to verify whether that email is already exist or not, if exists error must display. i have my code in express js, node js, angular 6 and mysql database and below is the code to create new user

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {    
    // Save to MySQL database
    let customer = req.body;
    Customer.create(customer).then(result => {      
        // Send created customer to client
        res.json(result);
    });
};
```

where should i use if statement in above code

Thanks in advance

Comment: check if the user exists before you call Customer.create...

Comment: Do you use sequelize as a ORM?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the simplest way of solving your problem is making the email column in the database unique. If you try to insert a new user with an already existing email the query will fail.

Another solution would be that you first do a query that looks in the database if an already existing user has the email (from req.body.email). But that would require having two different SQL queries, which I personally would not prefer.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using Sequelize ORM.

You can do like this

```
Customer.findOrCreate({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email,
    },
    // other datas needs to inserted
    defaults: {
      name: req.body.name,
      username: req.body.username,
    },
  }).spread((data, created) => {
    if (created) {
      // your logics
    } else {
      res.status(400).send(`${req.body.email} already exists.`);
    }
});
```